# Hi I want to use math.random to set the likely for it to repeat

Tags: java, random

I want to make a program that will generate a random number. I know I need to use Math.random() for this but I want to set a ratio for a number that can repeat. for example, I want the compiler to give a number from 1-10 but I want 5 repeat 3 times more than another number. how do I do that? please help thank you.

Comment: I don't think that is possible with Math.random. You have to write your own function to generate random numbers that way. You can use Math.random on it, but diferently.

Answer (score 2):

for exactly that case:

```
private static final int[] CHOICES = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
public static int strangeRandom() {
    return CHOICES[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(CHOICES.length)];
}
```

selects randomly from a given set of choices & you control the choices so that 5 is more likely.

Answer (score 1):

This will have the 5 come up at least 3 times as often as the other 9 numbers:

```
private static int getRandom ()
{
    Random r = new Random();

    int next = r.nextInt(100000) + 1;

    if (next <= 25000)
    {
        return 5;
    }
    else
    {
        return r.nextInt(10) + 1;
    }
}
```

**Note**: You can also preclude the 5 in the else case to try and hit the "3 times" likelihood better. I didn't for simplicity.

**Another Variation**:
Here is a variation that uses modulus of the `nextInt()` instead of 25000/100000 split.
Also, I put code in the else case that tries to preclude the 5 (without the infinite loop).

```
private static int getRandom ()
{
    Random r = new Random();

    int next = r.nextInt();

    if (next % 4 == 0)
    {
        return 5;
    }
    else
    {
        int p = r.nextInt(10) + 1;
        int tries = 0;

        // try to not get a 5 for a few times
        while (p == 5 && tries++ < 4)
        {
            p = r.nextInt(10) + 1;
        }
        return p;
    }
}
```

**Test Code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{       
    Map<Integer, Integer> frequecnyMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 12000; i++)
    {
        int r = getRandom();
        
        Integer n = frequecnyMap.get(r);
        
        if (n == null)
        {
            frequecnyMap.put(r, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            frequecnyMap.put(r, n + 1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(frequecnyMap);
}
```

**Sample Output (2nd Variation)**:

> {1=971, 2=975, 3=995, 4=1037, 5=3025, 6=1042, 7=995, 8=976, 9=969, 10=1015}
>
> {1=1016, 2=1019, 3=994, 4=968, 5=3068, 6=1030, 7=996, 8=914,
> 9=990, 10=1005}
>
> {1=939, 2=944, 3=979, 4=986, 5=3023, 6=1040, 7=1007, 8=1046, 9=997, 10=1039}

Comment: Ah I see, it is quite important to use 100k and 75k, instead of 4 and 3 :P.

Comment: Isn't it that 5 will have the frequency of 1/4 instead of the normal case of 1/10? In your code, it will have frequency of 3/4. Am I wrong?

Comment: @MaxG You are correct. The 75000 needs to be 25000. Will update. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use the [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class, not [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29). For one, it has the nice helper method [`nextInt(int n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) that generates a random integer between 0 and n-1 (inclusive).

In your particular case, you want a number 1-10, so generate 0-9 and add 1, i.e. `nextInt(10) + 1`.

But you want the number `5` to occur 3 times more often. A quick dirty way is the generate two extra number (1-12) and map them to 5.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int num = rnd.nextInt(12) + 1;
if (num == 11 || num == 12)
    num = 5;
```

As I said, quick and dirty, but it does the trick for your particular case.

---

Now, for a more generic solution, you want to be able to specify weighted probabilities. Numbers 1-4, 6-10 has a weight of 1, and 5 has a weight of 3.

What you then do is sum the weight (12), and generate a random number, then find the number where the accumulated weight exceeds the random number.

Here is a method for that:

```
private static int random(Random rnd, int ... weights) {
    if (weights.length < 2)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Need at least two weights");
    int total = 0;
    for (int weight : weights) {
        if (weight <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid weight: " + weight);
        if ((total += weight) < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Weight overflow");
    }
    for (int i = 0, val = rnd.nextInt(total); ; i++, val -= weights[i])
        if (val < weights[i])
            return i;
}
```

You could then call it like this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int num = random(rnd, 1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1) + 1;
```

Notice the `+1`, since the method is like `Random.nextInt(n)` and returns a number 0 to n-1, where n is the number of weights given.

You could easily turn it into a nice class, where the weights are given on the constructor, and the class manages the `Random` object for you.

Beware that performance will degrade as number of weights go up. There is a way to use `TreeMap` or `binarySearch` to improve that, but you need the class implementation, so it can prepare the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have full control of your random generated numbers, you should do something like this:

```
public class MyRandom {
    private int[] probability;
    private long[] ntimes;
    private long times;

    public MyRandom(int[] probability) {
        this.probability = new int[10];
        System.arraycopy(probability, 0, this.probability, 0, probability.length);
        ntimes=new long[10];
        for(int i=0; i < ntimes.length; i++)
            ntimes[i]=0;
        times=0;
    }

    public void showProbability() {
        for (long i : probability) {
            System.out.print(i+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public int random() {
        int t = 10;

        int r = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);
        double p = 0;
        if (times == 0) 
            p = 0;
        else
            p = ntimes[r-1]*100/times;

        System.out.println("P: "+p +" : "+probability[r-1]);
        while (p > probability[r-1] && t > 0) {
            r = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);
            p = ntimes[r-1]*100/times;            
            t--;
        }
        ntimes[r-1]++;
        times++;
        return r;
    }

    public long getOcurrences(int i) {
        return ntimes[i-1];
    }


    //This is an example of how to use it.        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] p = {5, 5, 5, 5, 30, 5, 5, 5, 10, 15};
        MyRandom mr = new MyRandom(p);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
            int r = mr.random();
            System.out.println("Id: "+i+" Number: "+r+" Ocurrences: "+mr.getOcurrences(r));
        }
    }
}
```